# Changing individual block apearance in moodle

Tags: css, block, moodle

Just started a new job and i have been tasked to work with MOODLE.
I want to make everything look nice and clean, but i can't find the option to change color of individual blocks. 
Is it even possible?
I can't find anyone with the same problem, so either i am dumb and it is obvious, or i am the first person ever to want to do this.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to style a block type - then every type of block has a CSS class matching its type (e.g. every 'Self completion' block has CSS class 'block_selfcompletion'). If you want to target a specific instance of a block (e.g. the 'self completion block on course 5'), check the HTML of the page in your browser (right-click + 'inspect element') and you should see it has a unique id (e.g. 'id="inst63"').

e.g.

```
.block_selfcompletion { background-color: red; }
#inst63 { background-color: green; }
```

As for adding that CSS to your site - if you have a custom theme, then add it into the theme CSS. If not, then many themes have an 'extra CSS' setting, which allows you to enter the CSS via the UI.